# What's the difference between "most like to say sorry" & "most likely to say sorry"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you explain the difference between "most like to say sorry" & "most likely to say sorry"?

> Who would you **most like to say sorry to?**
>
> Who would you **most likely to say sorry to?**

Comment: Please give the context!! (The first doesn't sound idiomatic.)

Comment: @Kate Bunting, The first one is from grammar book. I have edited my post.

Comment: Ah, that makes it clearer!

Comment: **like** is a verb.  **likely** is an adjective or adverb.  That explains some of the differences between the structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *would like to* do something, it would please you to do it.

If you *would be likely to* do something (*be* is missing from the second question), it's probable that you would do it.

Comment: Or you could say *to* is extra in the second question: Who would you most likely say sorry to?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, So, the second question is correct, right? There is no need to add "be" between "most" and "likely", isn't there? I can't understand what do you mean with "be is missing from the second question".

Comment: The phrase is _be likely to_, so the second one needs to be **Who would you be most likely to say sorry to?** (or @stangdon's alternative version).